# how to save data in json with php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file
`users.json`

```
{
  "Jessica Smith": {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "surname": "Smith",
      "email": "jessica.smith@alias.com",
      "pass": "jessicasmith",
      "sex": "female"
  },
  "Jessica Smith2": {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "surname": "Smith2",
      "email": "jessica.smith2@alias.com",
      "pass": "jessicasmith2",
      "sex": "female"
  },
}
```

PHP code

```
$file = fopen("users.json", a);
if(!$file) die ( "Error");
$value =      "given_name:".$name."\nfamily_name:".$surname."\nemail:".$email."\npass:".$psw."\nsex: ".$type."\n";
fwrite($file, $value);
fclose($file);
```

With this code I only add string `$value` after the last line,
there is a method where I can convert `$value` in json form??
I try to use `json_encode`.

```
string json_encode(mixed $add[$value]);
```

but it doesn't work.

For example, i want add Jessica Smith3 in `users.json`

```
  "Jessica Smith3": {
    "name": "Jessica",
    "surname": "Smith3",
    "email": "jessica.smith3@alias.com",
    "pass": "jessicasmith3",
    "sex": "female"
  },
```

Comment: This question seems very confused. No idea what you're actually asking.

Comment: invalid json . remove the ` },` comma (last)

Comment: You can't add individual json encoded strings to a json file as that will make the total invalid json. Instead you should read the json, parse it, add the values at the correct place, encode it and save it.

Comment: please explain what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $value is not valid JSON and the file manipulation produces an invalid JSON file.
You should use

```
$value =  array(  "given_name"=>$name,
                  "family_name"=>$surname,
                  "email"=>$email,
                  "pass"=>$psw,
                  "sex"=>type);
$file = fopen("users.json", a);
if(!$file) die ( "Error");
$f = json_decode( $file );
$f[] = $value;
$file = json_encode( $f );
fwrite($file, $value);
fclose($file);
```